# How to remove extra page details in crystal report

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I'm new in crystal report, i want to make a limit of number record that display in one page. I'm using this formula "if Remainder (RecordNumber, 11) = 0 then true else false"
It's works, I have 20 records it divided into two page. But at the end it shows an extra page header. Anyone know how to remove the extra page header? Please help, Thank You
[Extra page header after add limit details formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDZDf.png)

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: the problem is it show a extra page header in the page 3 @Jazb